# Modify Code from Year Timespan to Month/Week Timespans

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, bar-chart, timespan

I am making a stacked bar plot over a year time span where the x-axis is company names, y-axis is the number of calls, and the stacks are the months.

I want to be able to make this plot run for a time span of a month, where the stacks are days, and a time span of a week, where the stacks are days. I am having trouble doing this since my code is built already around the year time span.

My input is a dataframe that looks like this

```
pivot_table.head(3)
Out[12]: 
Month       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11   12 
CompanyName                                                                     
Customer1   17  30  29  39  15  26  24  12  36  21  18   15  
Customer2   4   11  13  22  35  29  15  18  29  31  17   14
Customer3   11   8  25  24   7  15  20   0  21  12  12   17
```

and my code is this so far.

First I grab a years worth of data (I would change this to a month or a week for this question)

```
# filter by countries with at least one medal and sort
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

#Only retrieve data before now (ignore typos that are future dates)
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]
# get first and last datetime for final week of data

range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - pd.DateOffset(years=1)

# take slice with final week of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
```

Then I create the pivot_table shown above.

```
###########################################################
#Create Dataframe
###########################################################

df = df.set_index('recvd_dttm')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

result = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.month, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
result.columns = ['Month', 'CompanyName', 'NumberCalls']
pivot_table = result.pivot(index='Month', columns='CompanyName', values='NumberCalls').fillna(0)
s = pivot_table.sum().sort(ascending=False,inplace=False)
pivot_table = pivot_table.ix[:,s.index[:30]]
pivot_table = pivot_table.transpose()
pivot_table = pivot_table.reset_index()
pivot_table['CompanyName'] = [str(x) for x in pivot_table['CompanyName']]
Companies = list(pivot_table['CompanyName'])
pivot_table = pivot_table.set_index('CompanyName')
pivot_table.to_csv('pivot_table.csv')
```

Then I use the pivot table to create an OrderedDict for Plotting

```
###########################################################
#Create OrderedDict for plotting
###########################################################


months = [pivot_table[(m)].astype(float).values for m in range(1, 13)]
names = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov", "Dec"]
months_dict = OrderedDict(list(zip(names, months)))

###########################################################
#Plot!
###########################################################


palette = brewer["RdYlGn"][8]

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("Month", "@months"),
        ("Number of Calls", "@NumberCalls"),
        ]
)
output_file("stacked_bar.html")
bar = Bar(months_dict, Companies, title="Number of Calls Each Month", palette = palette, legend = "top_right", width = 1200, height=900, stacked=True)
bar.add_tools(hover)


show(bar)
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to approach modifying this code so it can work for shorter time spans? This is what the graph looks like for a year

[image]

EDIT Added the full code. Input looks like this example:

```
CompanyName     recvd_dttm
Company1        6/5/2015 18:28:50 PM
Company2        6/5/2015 14:25:43 PM
Company3        9/10/2015 21:45:12 PM
Company4        6/5/2015 14:30:43 PM
Company5        6/5/2015 14:32:33 PM
```

Comment: How does your input change?

Comment: can you upload you sample data file pls? what's the original frequency before you make the pivot table?

Comment: @mpez0 right now my input is variable "days" that is either 7, 30, or 365 and pulls data from the last week, month, and year.

Comment: Are you using 30 and 365 as flags, or subtracting those as day counts? Because those are bad assumptions for days/month or days/year.

Comment: @mpez0 Yes, they are bad assumptions. I am going to change it to pd.DateOffset for a more accurate pull of data. However, that is not my focus for this question.

Comment: @JianxunLi Hi, how can I find the original frequency? I'm not sure what you mean by that. I added an input example, does that help? Do you need more?

Comment: @jenryb is it possible to upload your full data file with your full code script? (dropbox sharelink or google driver) I need to play with your real dataset to see how to deal with the situation. (I saw you post a series of questions, so with the data file, we perhaps can solve them all one-by-one) :-)

Comment: @JianxunLi I wish I could, that would be very helpful, but the data is proprietary so I can't share it :( Maybe I can make a sample? It's very large though, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @JianxunLi Maybe we could run the code through some other csv file like this one http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv ?

Comment: @JianxunLi or even better, here is a Consumer Complaints csv. I could modify my code for the sample data, fix it with you, then revert it back for my dataset?

Comment: @jenryb great. I'll try play with that sample data to see whether any solution comes up.

Comment: @jenryb can you also post the code how to generate `recvd_dttm` column based on the sample data file? I saw 12 columns in csv file but no one is named `recvd_dttm`

Comment: @JianxunLi Here, I made a mockup file that should help. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2010jiiuve6hy9/MOCK_DATA%20%281%29.csv?dl=0 I would read it in using df = pd.read_csv('MOCK_DATA.csv', usecols=[1, 4])